# C++ Select Multiple Occurances of a variable?

Tags: c++, keyboard-shortcuts, codeblocks, selection, multiple-cursor

I am new to C++, but I come from Python, and was starting C++ in a new semester. I remember in Python, you can select multiple occurrences. ATM I am using Code::Blocks.

So, when I start selecting a variable that pops up a few times, I see it highlights the other same variables in red, but I am only able to change one at a time. So I am looking for like a multiple-cursor type method where I can select all occurrences of a variable or word and rewrite them. For example, if I want to change 15 places where I used the variable name `weight` instead of `weightsKG` then I want to be able to select all at once, not CTRL-select. Or is that not possible?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Code::Blocks, does it have refactoring capabilities? If so, then just rename the source variable and let the refactor update all of the references to that variable.

Comment: This has nothing to do with C++, but everything to do with your IDE.  For example, in the IAR Electronic Workbench IDE, I can set up a project and search the entire project for a variable name.  Likewise with Visual Studio.  However, in Emacs, I would need to load all the symbols of the project before searching.

Answer (score 0):

In CodeBlocks, you can use the `Replace...` or `Replace in files...` command from the `Search` menu.
[image]
At this point a dialog will open where you will enter the text to be replaced and the updated one.
[image]
Pressing the `Replace` button will open another dialog where you can confirm one by one the replacement of the text, or you can replace all the occurrences in one go.
[image]
That's all.